# set the value of an object based on validation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update `validations` based on whether the value validates

If I set it using  `validations.isValid = false` this works

inside the function it shows `validations.isvalid` as false and outside it shows as `true`, how can I set this correctly to false if the value fails validation?

```js
export let validations = {
  validate: null,
  isValid: true,
  validationMessage: ''
};

export let validationsOptions = {
  shouldValidateUniquness: true
};

function validateInput(value, validationRules) {
  let options = {
    ...validations
  }
  switch (validationRules) {
    case 'day':
    case 'month':
    case 'date':
    case 'year':
      validateDate(value)
      break;
    case 'notEmpty':
      if (value == null || value.length === 0) {
        options = {
          ...validations,
          isValid: false
        }
        // Object.assign(validations,{...validations, isValid: false})
        // validations.isValid = false
      }
      break;
    case 'phone':
      if (value == null || value.length === 0 || !(new RegExp(/^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$/).test(value))) {}
      break;
    case 'numbersOnly':
      if ((value !== null && value !== '') && !(new RegExp(/^\d+$/).test(value))) {
        validations.isValid = false;
      }
      break;
    case 'email':
      if (!validateEmailFormat(value)) {
        options = false;
      }
      break;
    case 'minLength':
      if (value.length < minLength) {
        validations.isValid = false;
      }
      break;
  } {
    console.log(options)
  }
  return options
}
```

Comment: why are you destructuring validations into options and in some case updating options and other case updating validations ?

Comment: I was testing, could you suggest a  better way to do this?

Comment: If you modify `validations`, you're modifying the outside object. You should do `options.isValid = false` instead of `validations.isValid = false`. I don't know if thats sufficient, but the mix is definitely wrong.

(I don't know why this outside `validations` object exists at all, you could initialize `options` directly, or - if you're relying on the outcome of a previous `validateInput()` call, pass a validations object as a parameter (needs to be cloned internally))

Comment: [Maybe helpful](https://testbed.nicon.nl/showFiddle/mruyzafv)

Comment: I would like to update the outside object 'validations'

Answer (score 0):

To answer stricto to your requirement:

you do not want

```
  let options = {
    ...validations
  }
```

but

```
  // now modifying options does modify validations as well since they refer to the same object
  const options = validations
```

That said it is bad practice because you are inducing **side effects** (namely on validations which is out of the function. Kind of like a global (and you export it furthermore!)).

If you want `validations` to be modified, you may pass it as argument, and modify it "in place"

```
function validateInput(value, validationRules, options = {
  validate: null,
  isValid: true,
  validationMessage: ''
}) {
  ... //
  return options
}
const myOptions = { validate: null, isValid: true, validationMessage: '' }
const out = validateInput(.., .., myOptions)
// myOptions will be modified
// you can also access it via variable out
```

- If the caller did not provide the options, you get a new instance
- If he did, you modify the options he gave

If necessary, make a singleton for options (???), but give that instance to `validateInput`, so the cause of your doom is not `validateInput` but the giving of the single instance.

---

Finally the ol'preach: your function still has side effect (has per your requirement) but just in case keep in mind that **not modifying** options (as parameter) and returning a new instance would make your function pure and allow you to call it wherever whenever since there is no side effects.